# Vector of any type from given struct

Tags: c++, struct

Is there any way to create a vector of any type of given structures?

```
struct STUDENCI
{
    int indeks;
    string imie;
    string nazwisko;
};

struct PRZEDMIOTY
{
    int id;
    string nazwa;   
    int semestr;    
};

struct SALE
{
    string nazwa;
    int rozmiar;    
    bool projektor;
    double powierzchnia;
};

    vector<ANY TYPE FROM STUDENCI, PRZEDMIOTY, SALE> TAB[3];
```

Comment: I think this is a strong case of the [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'm pretty sure you don't actually need a vector of 3 different types. It looks like you are needlessly complicating things.

Comment: I have in another vector the names of structures (database table names). By parsing this vector I'm able to find the index of given table name. This is why I want to have container for data (structures listed above) also in vector. In this way I can get specific container (struct) by vector index.

Comment: @user3050705: At least at first blush, that sounds like you probably want an `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`).

Comment: May I suggest you translate some of variable names into English. Sounds 'up tight' I know, but something tells me that it might help us understand what you are trying to achieve, and let's face it, English is a rather mainstream language theses days.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a the variant library from boost (www.boost.org):

```
std::vector<boost::variant<STUDENCI, PRZEDMIOTY, SALE> > v;
```

E.g. **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6a5349188a76d78)**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string;

struct STUDENCI
{
    int indeks;
    string imie;
    string nazwisko;
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, STUDENCI const& v) {
        return os << "STUDENCI { " << v.indeks << ", " << v.imie << ", " << v.nazwisko << " }";
    }
};

struct PRZEDMIOTY
{
    int id;
    string nazwa;   
    int semestr;    
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, PRZEDMIOTY const& v) {
        return os << "PRZEDMIOTY { " << v.id << ", " << v.nazwa << ", " << v.semestr << " }";
    }
};

struct SALE
{
    string nazwa;
    int rozmiar;    
    bool projektor;
    double powierzchnia;
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, SALE const& v) {
        return os << "SALE { " << v.nazwa << ", " << v.rozmiar << ", " 
                  << std::boolalpha << v.projektor << ", " << v.powierzchnia << " }";
    }
};

typedef std::vector<boost::variant<STUDENCI, PRZEDMIOTY, SALE> > Vector;

int main()
{
    Vector v;
    v.push_back(STUDENCI { 1, "imie", "nazwisko" });
    v.push_back(PRZEDMIOTY { 1, "eng101", 3 });
    v.push_back(SALE { "auditorium", 42, true, 250 });

    for (auto& element: v)
        std::cout << element << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
STUDENCI { 1, imie, nazwisko }
PRZEDMIOTY { 1, eng101, 3 }
SALE { auditorium, 42, true, 250 }
```

Comment: @0x499602D2 I've added an example

Comment: Cannot open include file boost/variant.hpp ;/

Comment: @user3050705 You would need to [get and install boost](http://www.boost.org/users/download/) on your system.

Comment: This is a project for the school lab, so I can't do that.

Comment: IIRC varaiant is a header only thing, like most of boost.

Comment: @user3050705 Yeah. A school project, I gathered. Which is _exactly_ why you need to tell us /what you are trying to achieve/ instead of /how you are trying to achieve it/ (the XY-problem!). Because, you're not going about it the right way :)

Comment: simple database system for storing, adding, selecting and saving data.

Comment: So you need three separate tables. No need to have "one table".

Comment: but how should I refer to the table if its name is not given?
I can't do something like this (written in PHP): $table = $_POST['table']; $object->$table so i decided to find the index: int index = findIndexByTableName(table); cout << TAB[index]

Comment: `int index = findIndexByTableName(); switch (index) { case TABLE1: readTable1Record(line); break; case TABLE2:  readTable2Record(line); case TABLE3: readTable3Record(line); }` - just a thought. They're _different_ tables anyway. Abstracting that is highly likely way over your school'd budget :)

Answer (score 1):

That's what unions are for, see the reference for more information on the topic:
[Union declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)

Comment: Please don't tell beginners to write unions. Unions are the fast lane to UB, especially if the user doesn't know what UB is.

Comment: Agreed, unions are a terrible idea. They have there place, and that is not here. Variant is a much better solution.

Comment: @sehe: I agree that in that case variant is better. I upvoted your answer.